# Why can't I reuse a driver in the newest version of selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

``

Hi, last time I used selenium was 2-3 years ago, now that I come back to it I realise a lot of things have changed, and one of them is that after running the code chromedriver automatically closes and aparently the only way to keep it open is using this command

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

Using these lines of code keeps it open after the code stops but it makes the driver that already is opened  unable to be used again with the following commands on another script

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities={})

driver.session_id = session_id
```

because I get the following error:

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=57349): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000022FFDB034F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))

To summarize, I use two scripts, one only for opening chrome, then I manually do some things because is better not to automate them, and then when I´m ready I run another script that uses the previously opened chrome and starts where I left it. If I use an older version of selenium like 3.0, chrome do not close automatically and I can reuse the driver with its url and session ID that I store in an excel document to use them on the second script. The problem is, newer versions of selenium closes automatically chrome and to keep it alive I have to use detach option but I suspect this option is the one who causes the error above. Can someone explain this to me? is there a way to work around this?, I can just use the old version of selenium but I'm afraid it becomes no longer available and selenium forces me to use newer version or something like that, thanks.

FULL CODE THAT OPENS CHROME:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
s = Service(r'C:\Users\juanb\PycharmProjects\KT\chromedriver.exe')
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\juanb\PycharmProjects\KT\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
url = driver.command_executor._url
session_id = driver.session_id
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("DRIVER.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
sheet.cell(1, 2).value = session_id
sheet.cell(2, 2).value = url
wb.save("DRIVER.xlsx")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/?hl=es")
print(url)
print(session_id)
```

FULL CODE I USE TO DO WHAT I NEED:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("DRIVER.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
session_id = sheet.cell(1, 2).value
url = sheet.cell(2, 2).value
print(url)
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities={})  # ERROR OCCURS HERE
driver.session_id = session_id
.
.
.
```

I tried installing an older version of selenium and it worked, but like I said, I would like to know if t here is a way to do this on newer versions. Also I could not find a single person having this problem or solution on the internet.

Comment: Did you already try: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--no-quit"])`

Comment: Sorry for late response, I am busy at work. No, I haven´t tried it yet, let me check and I'll tell you if it work. thank you for your response

Comment: Caridorc, I have tried it and it does not work